# finding the confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

Please can I check this is the correct method for calculating the interval confidence of 95% where the variance is unknown:

````
Mean +/- (1.96 * Standard Deviation / sqrt(number of data points))
The Normal Distribution is: qnorm(0.975) 
The confidence intervals for Pacha:
B Value Upper value of the confidence interval: 97 + 1.959*6/sqrt(30) = $99.14598
A Value Lower value of the confidence interval: 97 - 1.959*6/sqrt(30) = $94.85402
Therefore,  (94.85402, 99.14598)

B Value Upper value of the confidence interval: 100.79 + 1.959*6/sqrt(30) = $102.936
A Value Lower value of the confidence interval: 100.79 - 1.959*6/sqrt(30) = $98.64402
Therefore, (98.64402,102.936)
```
````

Comment: What does the `*6` in the formulas represent?  Why aren't you using a Student t distribution?

Comment: The *6 is the multiplication by the SD What is the formula for the student t distribution if the variance is unknown, please

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Student+t+test), which provides that formula in many posts.

Comment: In case you haven't found it after 3 hrs: `qnorm(.975);  qt(.975, 29)` returns respective values 1.959964 and 2.04523. // Compare with printed t tables. // Also, for _normal_ it's 1.960, not 1.959,for 3-place accuracy.